# Getting the glyph width of a monospaced font

Tags: fonts, glyph, fontmetrics

Recently I asked on a different forum about the glyph width of the Source Code Pro font (it’s 600). This helps me in setting tab  stops in a word processor for code samples.

How do I find the glyph width of other Monospaced fonts?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve font metrics using [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js)

Once the font file is parsed, you can easily check many glyph or font properties against the retrieved objects:

```
let glyph = font.charToGlyph('m');
let glyphWidth = glyph.advanceWidth;
```

So far opentype.js does not support `woff2` files.

> Support for WOFF, OTF, TTF (both with TrueType glyf and PostScript cff
> outlines)

You can use [google webfont helpers api](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/api/fonts/source-code-pro) to fetch `woff` or `truetype` files.

Since some webfonts use 2048 units per em, you might calculate a normalized glyph width (relative to 1000 units per em):

```js
//source code pro (1000 units per em)
let fontURL0 =
  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcecodepro/v22/HI_diYsKILxRpg3hIP6sJ7fM7PqPMcMnZFqUwX28DMyQtMlrSg.woff";

//open sans (2048 units per em)
let fontURL1 =
  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v29/memSYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVZyOOSr4dVJWUgsjZ0B4gaVQ.woff";

getFontMetrics(fontURL0, "m", spanGlyphWidth0);
getFontMetrics(fontURL1, "m", spanGlyphWidth1);

function getFontMetrics(fontURL, char, span) {
  opentype.load(fontURL, function(err, font) {
    let unitsPerEm = font.unitsPerEm;
    let em1000Ratio = 1000 / unitsPerEm;
    let glyph = font.charToGlyph(char);
    let glyphWidth = glyph.advanceWidth;
    let glyphWidthRelative = +glyphWidth * em1000Ratio.toFixed(1);
    let fontName = font.tables.name.fullName.en;
    //console.log(font)
    span.textContent = `"${fontName}" – unitsPerEm: ${unitsPerEm} | width (absolute): ${glyphWidth} | width (relative to 1000 units/em): ${glyphWidthRelative} `;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@latest/dist/opentype.min.js"></script>

<p><span id="spanGlyphWidth0"></span></p>
<p><span id="spanGlyphWidth1"></span></p>
```